# How to generate an outline for a document?

Tags: packages, document-classes, automation, class-options

I am writing a debate case class in latex and I have environments set up so the user can easily declare a contention and subpoint. For example, if the user had:

Contention 1: My solution is better

Subpoint a: My opponent's solution is worse
Then here is the actual bulk of the argument that doesn't need to be in the outline

(the way you would do this using my class is:

```latex
\begin{contention}{1}{My solution is better}
\begin{subpoint}{a}{My opponent's solution is worse}
Then here is the actual bulk of the argument that doesn't need to be in the outline)
\end{subpoint}
\end{contention}
```

Then I would want to put something in the class that would automatically generate an outline that would look like:

```
C1) My solution is better
    a) My opponent's solution is worse
```

And then the rest of the case, and so on. Is there any way, in the debate class, that I can have that outline automatically generated?

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\contention\section
\let\subpoint\subsection
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Outline}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\contention{My solution is better}
\subpoint{My opponent's solution is worse}
Then here is the actual bulk of the argument 
that doesn't need to be in the outline
\subpoint{My opponent's solution is worse}
More arguments that doesn't need to be in the
outline
\contention{Another contention}
\subpoint{Another subpoint}
\subpoint{More subpoints}
\contention{One more contention}
\end{document}
```

If you want the `\subpoint` enumerated as `a)`, `b)`, ... use:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection})}
```

Comment: Oh I did not think of that, thank you!